# Beamer Equation Display Error

Tags: beamer, arrows, brackets

When I try to use the following code, the right bracket on both equations do not show up on my compiled PDF. I wanted the down arrow above the first plus sign to more or less centre it on the page (if I put the down arrow above the equal sign, the right bracket shows up). It does compile, but also gives me the compiling error: "Extra } or forgotten \right". I think the error is related to the equation, rather than elsewhere in the code.

How can I correct this? I think I have shown all of the relevant included packages below, but there are more which I am using as well. Thanks in advance!

Also, it would be nice to be able to pause the slide between showing the first equation and the arrow, as well as between the arrow and second equation. Trying this gave me other display issues.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
    draw,
    fill=red,
    single arrow,
    minimum height=3.5ex,
    single arrow head extend=1ex
    }
}
\newcommand{\arrowup}{%
\tikz [baseline=-0.5ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=90] {};}
}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{%
\tikz [baseline=-1ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=-90] {};}
}

\usecolortheme[RGB={225,0,0}]{structure}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Spatial Modelling}
And, for the 3-dimensional case:\pause
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = D \left( \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} & + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2} \right) \\
  & \arrowdown \\
\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}  = D \left( \frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial x^2} & + \frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial z^2} \right)
\end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the reason, but the usage of & in between the \left( and \right) is the cause for the error. This works:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
    draw,
    fill=red,
    single arrow,
    minimum height=3.5ex,
    single arrow head extend=1ex
    }
}
\newcommand{\arrowup}{%
\tikz [baseline=-0.5ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=90] {};}
}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{%
\tikz [baseline=-1ex] \node [myarrow,rotate=-90] {};
}

\usecolortheme[RGB={225,0,0}]{structure}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Spatial Modelling}
And, for the 3-dimensional case:
\pause

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = 
    D \left( \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} \right. & + 
    \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2} + 
    \left. \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2} \right) \\
  & \arrowdown \\
\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}  = 
    D \left( \frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial x^2} \right. & + 
    \frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial y^2} + 
    \left. \frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial z^2} \right)
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I added a \right. before the & and a \left. before the last term.

Comment: the reason is that each "cell" of an `align` (like each cell of a table) is processed as an independent unit, and the `\left ... \right` notation must be complete within a unit.